# Migration to material ui v.4 x x problem with css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, updates

i have a difficult task of migrating the material ui version from 0.20 to 4.9.0 (the latest). I've changed all the imports and changes of components but i have a MAJOR problem with the css. We use a main.scss file where we custom our components. Suppose we talk about the AppBar component. In the old material ui version i have the component code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/Select';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const AppBarTop = () => (
  <div className="euro-header">
    <AppBar className="euro-appbar">
      <DropDownMenu
        className="euro-usermenu"
        value={1}
        selectedMenuItemStyle={styles.selected}
        menuStyle={styles.popup}
      >
        <MenuItem
          value={1}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Ιστορικό Λαθών"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={2}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Ιστορικό χρήστη"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={3}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Διαχείριση προφίλ"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={4}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Αποσύνδεση"
        />
      </DropDownMenu>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
);
```

and the css classed are these:

```
.euro-header {
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:999!important;
}

.euro-appbar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
}

.euro-appbar > button > div > svg {
  fill:rgb(0, 0, 0)!important;
}
.euro-usermenu {
  height:50px!important;
  margin:7px 0 0 20px!important;
  padding-left:40px!important;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0px 0px;
}

.euro-usermenu > div > div {
  margin-top:-1px;
  border:0px!important;
}

.euro-usermenu svg {
  fill:#000!important;
}
```

The output is this:
[image]

Now with the updated material ui version i rewrite my component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';


const styles = {
  selected: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  popup: {
    width: '230px',
  },
};

/** Renders the application's main upper bar */

const AppBarTop = () => (
  <div className="euro-header">
    <AppBar
      position="static"
      className="euro-appbar"
      zDepth={1}
      showMenuIconButton
    >
      <Select
        className="euro-usermenu"
        value={1}
        selectedMenuItemStyle={styles.selected}
        menuStyle={styles.popup}
      >
        <MenuItem
          value={1}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Ιστορικό Λαθών"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={2}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Ιστορικό χρήστη"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={3}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Διαχείριση προφίλ"
        />
        <MenuItem
          value={4}
          label="Δημήτρης Παπαδόπουλος"
          primaryText="Αποσύνδεση"
        />
      </Select>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
);


export default AppBarTop;
```

with the exact same css. Also i used StypesProvider injectFirst for overriding the material ui styles
but the output is something like this:
[image]

Do you know what can i do to fix this? Should i change all the css classes?
Thanks!

Comment: have you followed steps from https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

Comment: Yes! But the problem is with the css, should i rewrite it from scratch?